# Execute nii2mnc in matlab

Tags: linux, matlab, nifti, minc

I am trying to make a script in MATLAB that runs also some commands. Everything works fine so far except from the `nii2mnc`. I am getting different results when i run it in cmd and when i run it through my script in MATLAB.

At first the problem was the version of `nii2mnc` i was using. I fixed that and i am using the same version in both.

```
$ which nii2mnc
/data/lfs2/software/ubuntu14/minc-itk4-1.9.11-20160202/bin/nii2mnc
```

The mnc files i am getting though have different sizes (the one from my script is bigger).

Any suggestions?

Comment: ...how are you running DOS commands while it is a linux executable?

Comment: Can you show us the actual call to `nii2mnc`, in both MATLAB and DOS?

Comment: i can run it with 3 different ways `dos()` `system()` `unix()` i just chose `dos()` as they are all giving the same output.
In cmd:
`nii2mnc CT.nii CT_mnc.mnc`
In MATLAB (after setting the PATH and the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and getting the path and the name of the NifTi file):
`dos(['nii2mnc ' fullfile(ctpath, CTName) ' CTmnc.mnc']);`